# How to generate a deterministic Minesweeper board?

Tags: algorithm, minesweeper

We're developing a [Minesweeper game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.popoko.minesweeper). Currently the board is generated randomly and so a large percentage of the games, especially on larger grids, require guessing, i.e. there will be multiple solutions that correspond to some given state of the board, and the players don't like that too much. Is there a good algorithm to use to generate a Minesweeper board that do not require guessing?

The initial board has all cell hiddens, and we made sure the first move is never a bomb. The board generator is triggered only after the first move.

Comment: but the first move in minesweeper is always guessing, right?

Comment: Please add more information. Does the initial board need to have all cells hidden, or can some (numbers) be revealed at the very start? What are the strategies you have thought of so far? What are the problems with those?

Comment: @manzet We made sure the first move is never a bomb - this is easy. Generator only starts after the first move is made.

Comment: @trincot Added more information.

Comment: Do you mean that at any point in the game the player can always find  one cell whose state is completely determined by the history of the uncovered cells so far?

Comment: @JuanCarlosRamirez yes , there should be exactly one solution for the game given the uncovered cells

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate a minesweeper board which doesn't need guessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304982/generate-a-minesweeper-board-which-doesnt-need-guessing)